# Ruby way for data serialization and simple postprocessing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm still new to ruby. I have model Point and I need serialized and processed data from it, I wrote this code:

```
    points = Point.joins(:tracksegment).where('tracksegments.track_id' => track.id).to_a

    prev_point = nil

    points.each do |point|
      if prev_point != nil
        @fl_time += point.point_created_at - prev_point.point_created_at
        @points << {:fl_time => point.point_created_at - prev_point.point_created_at,
                :fl_time_abs => fl_time,
                :elevation_diff => (prev_point.elevation - point.elevation).round(2),
                :elevation => point.elevation.round(2),
                :abs_altitude => point.abs_altitude,
                :latitude => point.latitude,
                :longitude => point.longitude,
                :distance => point.distance.to_i,
                :h_speed => point.h_speed.round(2),
                :v_speed => point.v_speed.round(2),
                :glrat => (point.h_speed.round(2) / point.v_speed.round(2)).round(2)
        }
      end
      prev_point = point
    end
```

Is there any way to make it more compact and make it amazing (true ruby (or rails) way)?

I thought about `.map(&:serilizable_hash)` but it returns strings as a keys not symbols.

Also I thought about `each_proc(2) do |prev, curr|`, but it's some kind of converting, not just changing current element of array.

Comment: Why not use an actual serialization format like JSON or YAML to do the work for you?

Comment: @b4hand, don't know how to implement :fl_time, :elevation_diff, :glrat calcs with it?

Comment: Just don't round. In the long run you probably don't want to do that. Alternatively they both provide hooks for doing customized serialization.

Comment: @b4hand about rounding - I'll going to do it before record to DB, but I don't store :glrat, :elevation_diff and :fl_time in DB.

Comment: You should mention that this is for a db and not an external format as that changes the answers significantly.

Comment: @b4hand it's not for db, I query db for this data, process it and pass to views as json, but now use `.to_json.htm_safe`